# How do I efficiently reverse the last seven bits of a 16-bit integer in MIPS?

Tags: performance, assembly, mips

For example, if I have an integer that can be represented as 01234567, then I need to reverse it and preserve the first bit so it looks like 07654321. I also need to do this as efficiently as possible.

I already found this online:

```
for (x=0;x<8;x++) {
bit = input & 0x01; // get the low bit
output |= bit; // set the low bit in output
input >> 1; // shift to the right for AND mask
output << 1; // move all bits to the left, low bit = 0 now
}
```

And to implement that (plus keeping the first bit at the beginning) I wrote this:

```
    andi $7, $8, 0xC000     #$7: obtain the first two bits that we want to save
    sll $7, $7, 2           #$7: sll to make it possible to later append $7 on to the beginning

Flip:andi $4, $8, 0x03      #$4: bitwiseAND the reference with 0x03 to isolate last two bits
    or $5, $5, $4           #$5: store the bit using bitwiseOR 
    sll $5, $5, 2           #$5: sll $5 to create space for the next two bits to be loaded in 
    srl $8, $8, 2           #$2 slr $8 so the next two bits can be isolated
    addi $13, $13, -1       # decrease counter
    bne $13, $0, Flip       # if $13 is not equal to zero, then branch to start of Flip 

    or $5, $5, $7           # add the saved bit back onto the beginning 
    srl $5, $5, 2           # srl to get rid of the execess zeros at the end
```

(After looking at other questions here, I realize my format is different than the norm - this is just how I was taught in class)

That code works, but I'm looking for a more efficient way to implement it. Can anyone offer guidance on how to improve this?

Comment: It's likely the fastest will be a 128 byte or word lookup table. Mask out the lo 7, use this value to look up a byte or word that is the bit flipped index, and or this value into the lo 7 of the original value. About 8 instructions. The table easily fits L1 cache.

Answer (score 2):

Using a lookup table with a bit of logic is a very efficient solution. A simple table like suggested by Gene would work, or you could try multiple [bit hack solutions](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseTable) for a memory/speed tradeoff (you probably want no 64-bit because you're using MIPS).